# Insert time into a field only when selected and then click

Tags: javascript

The time only inserts on the first field https://jsfiddle.net/cjy28u1o/. I want to insert the time based on the field that is ***selected***.

```
$('#time').click(function(){
  var time = new Date();                
  $('#time-holder').val(time.toTimeString());  
});
```

Comment: I think it should be `time.getTime().` See [here.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/date_gettime.htm)

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any answer by click upper gray triangle

Comment: you need to insert time in the text box which is selected is it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the focused element using [`.focusin()`](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) in a variable and then set it's value when click. Also using the attribute *class* instead of *id* is more meaningful in this case:

```js
$(function(){
  var $focused;
  $('.time-holder').focusin(function(){
    $focused = $(this);
  });
  $('#time').click(function(){
    var time = new Date();
    if($focused != undefined)
      $focused.val(time.toTimeString()); 
    else
      alert('Not focused any element');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" class="time-holder">
<input type="text" value="" class="time-holder">
<input type="text" value="" class="time-holder">

<input type="button" value="time" name="timer" id="time">
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML DOM, id is unique.

If you put same id for multiple elements, DOM and jQuery will fire event on first matched element with the specified id.

Rest of the elements will be simply ignored.

You need to add class to all elements as multiple elements can have same class.

This way, you will get time for all text fields.

So, your code corrected now:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder" class="time-text">
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder2" class="time-text">
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder3" class="time-text">

<input type="button" value="time" name="timer" id="time">
```

And Javascript:

```
$(function(){
 $('#time').click(function(){
  var time = new Date();                
  $('.time-text').val(time.toTimeString());  
 });
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$(
    function(){
        let lastFocusEl=null;
        
        $('#time').click(function(){
                  var time = new Date();                     
                  if(lastFocusEl) lastFocusEl.value = time.toTimeString();  
        });
        
        let f = function() { lastFocusEl=this};
        $('#time-holder').focus(f);
        $('#time-holder2').focus(f);
        $('#time-holder3').focus(f);

    }  
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder">
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder2">
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder3">

<input type="button" value="time" name="timer" id="time">
```

Answer (score 0):

> the time is only insert on first field

It is happening because, You have given the diffrent IDs to all the three elements.You are only targeting the first element. You should use `class` instead. Try this,

```
<input type="text" value="" class="time-holder"> <input type="text" value="" class="time-holder"> <input type="text" value="" class="time-holder">

<input type="button" value="time" name="timer" id="time">


JS CODE:



$(
    function(){

        $('#time').click(function(){
                  var time = new Date();                
                  $('.time-holder').val(time.toTimeString());  
        });

    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would listen to the *focus* event, and then set the time to the last focused element.

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){
    this.dataset.selected = true;
});
$('#time').click(function(){
          var time = new Date();
          var selectInput = $('[data-selected="true"]');
          selectInput.val(time.toTimeString());  
});
```